# When i call Method of Parent Class Using Super.displayInfo Values are not printing

Tags: java

**Question**
[image]

*Here is My Code *
*I need to Override displayInfo Method. so i have used super.displayInfo and than printing interest calculated by the respective class savings or fixed deposit. the interest is getting printed but other details account no , customer name , type and branch name are getting printed as default values like 0 and null.
*

```
import java.util.*;

class Account {
    int Acno;
    String CustName, type, Branch;

    void getCustInfo(int n, String nm, String ty, String br) {
        Acno = n;
        CustName = nm;
        type = ty;
        Branch = br;
    }

    void displayInfo() {
        System.out.println("Account No: " + Acno + "\nCustomer Name: " + CustName + "\nAccount Type: " + type
                + "\nBranch: " + Branch);
    }
}

class Savings extends Account {
    int Year;
    double Amount, Rate = 3.5, Interest;

    void getSavingsInfo(int y, double am) {
        Year = y;
        Amount = am;
    }

    void calIntAmt() {
        Interest = (Amount * Rate * Year) / 100;
    }

    void displayInfo() {
        super.displayInfo();
        System.out.println("Interest: " + Interest);
    }
}

class FixedDeposit extends Account {
    int Year;
    double Amount, Rate, Interest;

    void getFDInfo(int y, double am) {
        Year = y;
        Amount = am;
    }

    void calIntAmt() {
        if (Year <= 2) {
            Rate = 6.5;
            Interest = (Amount * Rate * Year) / 100;
        } else if (Year >= 2 && Year <= 5) {
            Rate = 7.5;
            Interest = (Amount * Rate * Year) / 100;
        } else if (Year >= 5 && Year <= 10) {
            Rate = 8.5;
            Interest = (Amount * Rate * Year) / 100;
        } else if (Year >= 10) {
            Rate = 9.0;
            Interest = (Amount * Rate * Year) / 100;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Year");
        }
    }

    void displayInfo() {
        super.displayInfo();
        System.out.println("Interest");
    }
}

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Account Number: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Customer Name: ");
        String nm = sc.next();

        System.out.print("Account Type: ");
        String t = sc.next();

        System.out.print("Btanch Name: ");
        String br = sc.next();

        System.out.print("Amount: ");
        int a = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Year: ");
        int y = sc.nextInt();

        Account ac = new Account();
        ac.getCustInfo(n, nm, t, br);

        if (t.equals("Saving")) {
            Savings s = new Savings();
            s.getSavingsInfo(y, a);
            s.calIntAmt();
            s.displayInfo();
        } else if (t.endsWith("FixedDeposit")) {
            FixedDeposit fd = new FixedDeposit();
            fd.getFDInfo(y, a);
            fd.calIntAmt();
            fd.displayInfo();
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

[image]

I was expecting result as
Account No: 1
Customer Name: abc
Account Type: Saving
Branch: aaa
Interest: 1750.0

Comment: You set the branch information on `ac`, not `s` or `fd`. They are completely separate instances, you need to set the branch information on whichever ones you want to call `displayInfo` on. (BTW, don't call a method which sets things on an account "get" something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, you should always name your method as "setXXX" if all you are doing in the method is to set the values for instance variables.

So Set methods "set" values and Get methods "get"(return) instance variable values

In your code, you are creating two different objects,

```
Account ac = new Account();
ac.getCustInfo(n, nm, t, br);
```

here you are setting

```
Acno = n;
CustName = nm;
type = ty;
Branch = br;
```

in object "ac".

Then you are creating a totally different Savings object

```
Savings s = new Savings();
s.getSavingsInfo(y, a);
s.calIntAmt();
s.displayInfo();
```

where you are setting only the year, amount and interest. This object never calls the method which initializes Account, customer name, branch and type. That is why those values are null.

The clean way to do this is as follows, I have cleaned up your example

```
import java.util.Scanner;

abstract class Account {
    int accountNumber;
    String customerName, accountType, branch;

    public Account(int accountNumber, String customerName, String accountType, String branch) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.customerName = customerName;
        this.accountType = accountType;
        this.branch = branch;
    }

    void displayAccountInfo() {
        System.out.println("Account No: " + accountNumber + "\nCustomer Name: " + customerName + "\nAccount Type: " + accountType
                + "\nBranch: " + branch);
    }

    abstract void calculateInterest();
}

class Savings extends Account {
    int year;
    double amount, rate = 3.5, interest;

    public Savings(int accountNumber, String customerName, String accountType, String branch, int year, int amount) {
        super(accountNumber, customerName, accountType, branch);
        this.year = year;
        this.amount = amount;

        calculateInterest();
    }

    void calculateInterest() {
        interest = (amount * rate * year) / 100;
    }

    void displayAccountInfo() {
        super.displayAccountInfo();
        System.out.println("Interest: " + interest);
    }
}

class FixedDeposit extends Account {
    int year;
    double amount, rate, interest;

    public FixedDeposit(int accountNumber, String customerName, String accountType, String branch, int year, int amount) {
        super(accountNumber, customerName, accountType, branch);
        this.year = year;
        this.amount = amount;

        calculateInterest();
    }

    void calculateInterest() {
        if (year <= 2) {
            rate = 6.5;
            interest = (amount * rate * year) / 100;
        } else if (year >= 2 && year <= 5) {
            rate = 7.5;
            interest = (amount * rate * year) / 100;
        } else if (year >= 5 && year <= 10) {
            rate = 8.5;
            interest = (amount * rate * year) / 100;
        } else if (year >= 10) {
            rate = 9.0;
            interest = (amount * rate * year) / 100;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Year");
        }
    }

    void displayAccountInfo() {
        super.displayAccountInfo();
        System.out.println("Interest: " + interest);
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Account Number: ");
        int accountNumber = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Customer Name: ");
        String customerName = sc.next();

        System.out.print("Account Type: ");
        String accountType = sc.next();

        System.out.print("Branch Name: ");
        String branch = sc.next();

        System.out.print("Amount: ");
        int amount = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Year: ");
        int year = sc.nextInt();

        Account account = null;

        if (accountType.equals("Saving")) {
            account = new Savings(accountNumber, customerName, accountType, branch, year, amount);
            account.displayAccountInfo();
        } else if (accountType.equals("FixedDeposit")) {
            account = new FixedDeposit(accountNumber, customerName, accountType, branch, year, amount);
            account.displayAccountInfo();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Account Type");
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

It is better to have Account class as abstract so that you can implement the calculateInterest in the sub classes.

I think you need to read more about Java inheritance to grasp these concepts

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inheritance-in-java/